# How to optimize database timezones with convert_tz or any other function

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I am trying to optimise my mySQL query when handling timezones.
My database (mySQL) is set to EET time(+02:00) (I will soon move on AWS where I will use UTC), but in any case, our Cakephp implementation has a setting that retrieves the records as UTC. Our `timestamp` column his a `timestamp` type.

So a `2019-12-19 12:44:27` found in our mySQL (+2), is actually `2019-12-19 10:44:27` (UTC) within our CakePHP implementation.

The thing is that I need to display rows between date ranges, for example today's results BUT according to the company's timezone and not according to server/database.

I have created the following query considering a `+04:00` timezone.

```
$company_timezone ='+04:00';
SELECT company_id, COUNT( timestamp ) AS views, url 
FROM behaviour 
WHERE company_id = 1
AND CONVERT_TZ(timestamp,'+00:00','{$company_timezone}')  >= DATE(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'+00:00','{$company_timezone}')) 
GROUP BY URL 
ORDER BY views 
DESC LIMIT 20
```

However this is quite needy in terms of performance. It takes approx 4-5 seconds. Without the `convert_tz` it takes no more than 0.5 sec.

My question is how can I optimise this? Of course, our `timestamp` column is indexed, even it doesn't make any sense at the specific query because I use it with `convert_tz`.

**new query that deals with date range (today - yesterday)**

*I believe the following example emphasizes more on my case:* With this query, I show the results based on the company's timezone. For example, if their company's local time is 00:01 then it is a new day for them, regardless the time of server/mysql.

```
SELECT COUNT(hash) as how_many
FROM   table          
WHERE  company_id = 1
AND CONVERT_TZ(last_visit,'+00:00','{$company_timezone}')  >= DATE(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'+00:00','{$company_timezone}') - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY date(last_visit)
ORDER BY last_visit DESC
```

Thank you

Comment: How is `timestamp` column populated in the first place?

Comment: @SalmanA with "current_timestamp". it is automatically by the database

Comment: Then I believe you can compare them directly `WHERE DATE(timestamp) = CURDATE()`. If you need to convert timezones then convert to `system` timezone and then compare.

Comment: Keep in mind that `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` work differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MySQL [documentation about the `TIMESTAMP` type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html):

> MySQL converts `TIMESTAMP` values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as `DATETIME`.) By default, the current time zone for each connection is the server's time. The time zone can be set on a per-connection basis.

Thus you are actually saving UTC-based values.  You may *think* you've stored UTC+2 values, but that's just because the default time zone at query time (the session time zone) is the same as the server's default time zone.

Additionally, functions like `NOW()` also use the session time zone.  Thus, since the session time zone is the same on both sides, there is no time zone conversion to be done. 
 You can just say:

```
AND timestamp >= NOW()
```

This has the added benefit (as [symcbean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59538497/634824) pointed out), of allowing the DBMS to use an index - in other words, the query becomes [sargable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/162263/23221).

You might also want to read the excellent article in the MySql documentation, [*Indexed Lookups from TIMESTAMP Columns*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-lookups.html), which explains how the session time zone impacts both indexed and non-indexed queries.

It might also be worthwhile to set the time zone explicitly to UTC at time of query:

```
SET time_zone = 'UTC';
```

You'll get the same results either way, but this is slightly more efficient as the DBMS now has fewer time zone conversions to perform.

---

For the second query in your edit, you still are showing a conversion on the left-side of the expression.  Again, you want that to be just the field so that an index can be used.  Since the field is a `TIMESTAMP` type, you simply need to calculate the earliest timestamp you want to retrieve.

If you want to do this inline your query, the number of conversions make it a bit convoluted:

```
SELECT COUNT(hash) as how_many
FROM   table          
WHERE  company_id = 1
  AND  last_visit >= CONVERT_TZ(DATE(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@session.time_zone, '{$company_timezone}')) - INTERVAL 1 DAY, '{$company_timezone}', @@session.time_zone)
GROUP BY DATE(CONVERT_TZ(last_visit, @@session.time_zone, '{$company_timezone}'))
ORDER BY DATE(CONVERT_TZ(last_visit, @@session.time_zone, '{$company_timezone}'))
```

For this reason, it's a lot easier to simply change the session time zone before your query such that it applies uniformly to all operations:

```
SET time_zone = '{$company_timezone}';
SELECT COUNT(hash) as how_many
FROM   table          
WHERE  company_id = 1
  AND  last_visit >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE(last_visit)
ORDER BY DATE(last_visit)
```

Comment: thank you for this, but I still struggle to understand... I have added another example I use that I believe is a better representation of my problem: When my local time goes 00:01 is a new day and I need to present the fresh rows, regardless the server/database timezone.

Comment: I've added to my answer in response to your edit.  But in the future please try to avoid asking multiple questions at once.  Instead, open a new question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have two solution for your question, hope one of them works for you

## Solution 1

Change timeZone of datetime in cakePHP and then execute query.

```
public static function convertDate($datetime, $companyTimeZone, $dbTimeZone)
{
    $newDate = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone($companyTimeZone));

    $newDate->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($dbTimeZone));
    return $newDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
$datetime = self::convertDate($datetime, $companyTimeZone, $dbTimeZone);

SELECT company_id, COUNT( timestamp ) AS views, url 
FROM behaviour 
WHERE company_id = 1
AND timestamp  >= $datetime 
GROUP BY URL 
ORDER BY views 
DESC LIMIT 20
```

## Solution 2

You can set timeZone of mysql for the current session only

```
##$company_timezone ='+04:00';

#NOTE this will set timZone only for the current session
SET time_zone= $company_timezone;

SELECT company_id, COUNT( timestamp ) AS views, url 
FROM behaviour 
WHERE company_id = 1
AND timestamp  >= NOW() 
GROUP BY URL 
ORDER BY views 
DESC LIMIT 20
```

**Note**: I have my application whose DB is UTC and users are coming from all over the globe, So I have implemented Solution 1 and it is working great since 2 year.

Comment: Does 'timestamp' DataType still have Range between 1970 and  '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC ?
If this is still true, your application will STOP functioning when you get to February, 2038 and you probably do not want to use timestamp DataType.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the same transformation to both sides of the predicate - all this does is make it impossible for the DBMS to use the index. Compare the values directly:

```
AND timestamp >= NOW()
```

This gets a bit more complicated if you are comparing data in one timezone with a wallclock in a different timezone - but you just need to make sure that you only apply the transformation to the side of the predicate which only contains literals, and not attribute references.

Comment: My mind is pretty complex right now regarding timezones so my question may sound stupid. Let's say a company is set to Singapore ( + 8 ). So when a record is saved from Singapore time at 10:00, a UTC time in database will be saved as 02:00. I don't clearly understand the logic behind `timestamp > now()` especially when I change the example to -8 hours instead.

Comment: I have edited my question and added one more example. With this query, I need to show the results based on the company's timezone. For example, if their time is 00:01 then it is a new day, regardless the time of server/mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to convert timestamp to (epoch conversion) long value as and save it to temporary column and then convert long value to timezone specific timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you a **real DIRTY method** !

This method, will don't alter your database, and will avoid any big computation (will not use the `convert_tz`) on the DB. But it will require some computation on the back-office (or front-office if you wan't to be more dirty...).

The dirty trick here is that you will do your time conversion only on the result and not on all data which are present in your db.

---

First you have to compute (and keep) the maximum time interval between :

- the company timezone
- the cakePHP server timezone
- DB server timezone

and

- the UTC timezone.

In your case it may be: **4H**.

Then

1-  **Add 4H** to your target `end_date`, then convert this date to a `end_timestamp`,
keep your `start_date` - without any modification - and convert this date to a `start_timestamp`.

2- Make your query using `start_timestamp` & `end_timestamp`. [This avoid any timezone and time conversion in your query]

*Note that you will get too much data (you will get "junk" data more especially near the `start_timestamp`) in your DB query result ...*

2- On your *back-office*: Filter bad element ( which mean you will have to remove all data which are between the previous `start_timestamp` and this same `start_timestamp` **+4H** ) to remove all junk data.

3- On your *back-office*: Finally convert the remaining results to the good timezone (UTC+4 in your case)

4- Send the data to the *front-office*.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the fact that the column is already of the type `timezone`, you don't need to use `convert_tz`. MySQL will always work with the current set time zone (that's one of the differences to the column type `datetime`).

So, you can set the timezone beforehand and then query without `convert_tz`. All indexes should be used.

```
SET timezone = '{$company_timezone}';

SELECT COUNT(hash) as how_many
FROM   table          
WHERE  company_id = 1
AND last_visit >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY DATE(last_visit);
ORDER BY last_visit DESC
```

You may use correct time zones like 'US/Eastern' directly. With this you will handle summer and winter time without any hassle. Here is how to set it up:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html